# Finding the constraint equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I am trying to solve a problem on Constraint equations for a triple pendulum model, but was not able to derive a constraint equation for the last mass.

[image]

I solved constraint equations for Masses 1 and 2 as follows, correct me if i am wrong:
Considering coordinates of Mass M1 as 
      \begin{pmatrix} 
  x1\\ 
  y1 
  \end{pmatrix}
Considering coordinates of Mass M2 as 
      \begin{pmatrix} 
  x2\\ 
  y2 
  \end{pmatrix}
and vectors
$$_{0}^{0}r_{1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
  x1\\ 
  y1 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
$$_{1}^{0}r_{2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
  x2-x1\\ 
  y2-y1 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
Then the constraint equation for first mass will be
$$x1^{2}+y1^{2}-L^{2} = 0$$
since it moves in a circle.
The constraint equation for the second mass will be
$$(x2 - x1)^{2}+(y2 - y1)^{2} - 2L^{2} = 0$$
The third mass will be perpendicular to the vector formed by M1 and M2, so the equation of normal(unit vector) will be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
  x2-x1\\ 
  y2-y1 
  \end{pmatrix} * \begin{pmatrix} 
  cos(90) &&-sin(90)\\ 
  sin(90) &&cos(90) 
  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 
  -(y2-y1)/2L\\ 
  (x2-x1)/2L 
  \end{pmatrix}$$
after that i couldn'd figure out how to proceed, I would be grateful if somebody give some hint what to do next.